# Can an FFI function modify a variable that wasn't declared mutable?

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {
    let val = 0;
    unsafe { foo(&val) }
}

extern "C" {
    pub fn foo(val: *const u32);
}
```

Implementation in C:

```c
void foo(unsigned* val) { *val=1; }
```

Of course, I should pass `val: *mut u32`, but what happens in the case that I pass an immutable reference? What compiler rules apply? Does `val` remain unchanged even though I'm passing a pointer to the local variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say [undefined behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html):

> Mutating non-mutable data — that is, data reached through a shared reference or data owned by a `let` binding), unless that data is contained within an `UnsafeCell<U>`.

And this might include:

- if you use `val` after the FFI-call it might ignore the writes you did (e.g. cached the value in a register or due to [constant propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding))
- segfault in FFI because the referenced memory might be read-only
- the write from FFI might show up in seemingly unrelated locations because the compiler reused the memory and assumed it had a well-defined value
- and worse :)