# What is the correct way to call an FFI function that swaps two values?

Tags: rust

I'm pretty new to Rust, and I'm trying to understanding the core concept of it which is ownership and borrowing. I already read the book and some other articles, but it still confuses me.

I have a struct defined like this:

```
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Element(pub (crate) [u64; 12]);
```

I have an external function which swaps the values of two `Element` based on the `flag` value. If `flag` is 0, they are not swapped, and if `flag` is 1, they are swapped. That's why in the prototype I use `&mut`:

```
extern {
    pub fn swap(x: &mut Element, y: &mut Element, flag: u8);
}
```

I create a wrapper method in Rust around this external function:

```
impl for Element {
    fn wrapper_swap(&mut self, y: &mut Element, flag: u8) {
        unsafe {
            swap(self, y, flag); // OR swap(&mut self, &mut y, flag); ?!
        }
    }
}
```

My `wrapper_swap` function has the same signature as the external prototype function `swap`. How do I need to call the external function `swap` here?

Since `self` and `y` already are defined as `&mut self` and `&mut y`, can I just call the swap function as `swap(self, y, flag);`? Or will that remove the mutable references, and actually I need to call it as `swap(&mut self, &mut y, flag);`?

It also gets complicated for me as to how I call it with actual values. For example, I have three variables defined like this:

```
let mut one = Element([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]);
let mut two = Element([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]);
let flag: u8 = 0;
```

Since the variables are already defined as mutable, do I need to call the `wrapper_swap` function as `(&one).wrapper_swap(&two, flag);` or will this  make references immutable no matter that the variables are defined as mutable, and instead I need to call it as `(&mut one).wrapper_swap(&mut two, flag);`? Which is the correct approach?

Maybe it's because I'm using unsafe functions, but the compiler does not complain about how I call this function.

What would happen if the variables `one` and `two` were not defined as mutable? Can I still borrow them mutable as `&mut one` or `&mut two`, and change their value in another function?

Comment: [**One** question per post, please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829).

Comment: See also [Can an FFI function modify a variable that wasn't declared mutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47620011/155423)

Comment: For what it's worth, your question doesn't really have anything to do with ownership or borrowing, both of which usually refer to how long a given value is valid.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks, and sorry for multiple questions. I checked the question that you have linked. Since, I do not have enough reputation to comment there, I will ask here. In the question that you have linked I see that the OP asks modifying a parameter that is marked as `const` inside the function. But, what I see in his `main` function is that the `val` variable is also not defined as `mut`. Now, what I don't understand is what is the proper way to call it? Just `foo(&val)` or `foo(&mut val)` assuming `val` is not `mut`, or to define the `val` as `mut` and do `foo(&val)` or `foo(&mut val)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have answered your question with a minimal amount of exploration. Don't be afraid to *try* things when programming; you are usually very unlikely to lose anything of value.

For example...

**build.rs**

```
extern crate cc;

fn main() {
    cc::Build::new()
        .file("src/swap.c")
        .compile("repro");
}
```

**src/swap.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int32_t *a, int32_t *b) {
  printf("Swapping %p, %p\n", a, b);

  int32_t t = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = t;
}
```

**src/main.rs**

```
extern crate libc;

use libc::int32_t;

extern "C" {
    fn swap(a: &mut int32_t, b: &mut int32_t);
}

fn swap_wrapper_1(a: &mut i32, b: &mut i32) {
    unsafe { swap(a, b) }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = 1;
    let mut b = 2;

    swap_wrapper_1(&mut a, &mut b);
    println!("{}, {}", a, b);
}
```

This prints:

```
Swapping 0x7ffee1cf9ff0, 0x7ffee1cf9ff4
2, 1
```

If you attempt to use your second form:

```
fn swap_wrapper_2(a: &mut i32, b: &mut i32) {
    unsafe { swap(&mut a, &mut b) }
}
```

You get a bunch of warnings:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable argument `a` as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:15:15
   |
14 | fn swap_wrapper_2(a: &mut i32, b: &mut i32) {
   |                   - consider changing this to `mut a`
15 |     swap(&mut a, &mut b)
   |               ^ cannot borrow mutably
```

If you fix that and then call both forms back-to-back, you get:

```
Swapping 0x7ffee7483f60, 0x7ffee7483f64
2, 1
Swapping 0x7ffee7483f60, 0x7ffee7483f64
1, 2
```

That's right — it's swapping the exact same addresses. That's because Rust will [automatically dereference your value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28519997/155423) when it needs to to match the signature, so it doesn't matter as long as you've defined the FFI signature correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response.