# Is it undefined behavior to mutate an immutable local variable?

Tags: rust, immutability, undefined-behavior

[The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html) seems to say that mutating an immutable local data (that's not inside an `UnsafeCell`) is undefined behavior:

> #### Behavior considered undefined
>
> - Mutating immutable data. All data inside a const item is immutable. Moreover, all data reached through a shared reference or data owned by an immutable binding is immutable, unless that data is contained within an `UnsafeCell<U>`.

The following code mutates an immutable local variable by reinterpreting it as an `AtomicU32`. Currently the code runs just fine and prints the expected result, but is its behavior actually undefined?

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicU32, Ordering};

#[repr(C, align(4))]
struct Bytes([u8; 4]);

fn main() {
    let bytes = Bytes([11; 4]);
    let x = unsafe { &*(&bytes as *const Bytes as *const AtomicU32) };
    x.store(12345, Ordering::SeqCst);
    println!("{:?}", bytes.0); // [57, 48, 0, 0]
}
```

Miri doesn't complain about the code example below where the bytes are mutable. Since those bytes are being mutated through a shared reference (`&AtomicU32`), it seems to me that according to *The Rust Reference* the code below should also have undefined behavior - given that *"all data reached through a shared reference [..] is immutable"* and *"mutating immutable data [is considered undefined behavior]"*.

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicU32, Ordering};

#[repr(C, align(4))]
struct Bytes([u8; 4]);

fn main() {
    let mut bytes = Bytes([11; 4]);
    let x = unsafe { &*(&mut bytes as *mut Bytes as *const AtomicU32) };
    x.store(12345, Ordering::SeqCst);
    println!("{:?}", bytes.0); // [57, 48, 0, 0]
}
```

Comment: You're mutating `bytes` by reaching through an immutable reference `&bytes`, which the quote in your question pretty clearly says is undefined behavior. What else would you expect?

Comment: I was just looking for a confirmation of the reference text. Do you have any thoughts about my follow-up code example?

Comment: The follow-up example is fine, because the `&AtomicU32` is derived from a `&mut Bytes`. `&*(&bytes as *const AtomicU32)` would be unsound even though `bytes` itself is marked mutable, because the *provenance* of the pointer matters for what you can do with it. See also [Temporarily opt-in to shared mutation](https://ryhl.io/blog/temporary-shared-mutation/), it's basically the same thing using `Cell` but without `unsafe`. (Unfortunately there is no stable equivalent for `Atomic`s)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, according to Miri:

```
error: Undefined Behavior: trying to reborrow for SharedReadWrite at alloc1377, but parent tag <untagged> does not have an appropriate item in the borrow stack
 --> src/main.rs:8:22
  |
8 |     let x = unsafe { &*(&bytes as *const Bytes as *const AtomicU32) };
  |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ trying to reborrow for SharedReadWrite at alloc1377, but parent tag <untagged> does not have an appropriate item in the borrow stack
  |
  = help: this indicates a potential bug in the program: it performed an invalid operation, but the rules it violated are still experimental
  = help: see https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/blob/master/wip/stacked-borrows.md for further information
          
  = note: inside `main` at src/main.rs:8:22
  = note: inside `<fn() as std::ops::FnOnce<()>>::call_once - shim(fn())` at /playground/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:227:5
  = note: inside `std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::<fn(), ()>` at /playground/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:125:18
  = note: inside closure at /playground/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std/src/rt.rs:66:18
  = note: inside `std::ops::function::impls::<impl std::ops::FnOnce<()> for &dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe>::call_once` at /playground/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:259:13
  = note: inside `std::panicking::r#try::do_call::<&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe, i32>` at /playground/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std/src/panicking.rs:379:40
  = note: inside `std::panicking::r#try::<i32, &dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe>` at /playground/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std/src/panicking.rs:343:19
  = note: inside `std::panic::catch_unwind::<&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> i32 + std::marker::Sync + std::panic::RefUnwindSafe, i32>` at /playground/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std/src/panic.rs:396:14
  = note: inside `std::rt::lang_start_internal` at /playground/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std/src/rt.rs:51:25
  = note: inside `std::rt::lang_start::<()>` at /playground/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std/src/rt.rs:65:5
```

See also:

- [Can an FFI function modify a variable that wasn't declared mutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47620011/155423)
- [Do aliasing mutable raw pointers (*mut T) cause undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57364654/155423)

---

> since those bytes are being mutated through a shared reference (`&AtomicU32`)

[`AtomicU32` contains an `UnsafeCell`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.49.0/library/core/src/sync/atomic.rs#L1318-L1320), thus it meets the exemption criteria you've quoted:

```rust
        pub struct $atomic_type {
            v: UnsafeCell<$int_type>,
        }
```

This is part of the API as [`AtomicU32::from_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicU32.html#method.from_mut), no need for `unsafe`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to a useful tool (Miri). Do you have any thoughts about whether the follow-up code example I added to the question has undefined behavior?